# Scraping route data from web map

Tags: web-mapping

I am hoping to find a way to extract the bus route data from the live feed maps on this site: https://transit.unitegps.com/bsoob

I was able to find this by poking around in developer tools, but I'm not sure how to get this into a polyline format: https://transit.unitegps.com/bsoob_transit/php-mysql/public_transit.php?command=fetch&source=route&route_id=6607&header_id=474

This is not something I have experience doing.

Comment: What polyline format are you after?  Which tools/languages are you using?

Comment: It's JSON within JSON.  So first JSON decode the whole shebang, then JSON decode `result['Route_Points']`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a violation of the terms of service - if they want you to have the data then they will be happy to provide it if you ask. If they don't then it will probably be impossible to extract it legally.